# Graphics.Path.Direction - Java Enum Direction Issue - Cannot Use EAST

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi i have created a `Enum Direction`

```
public enum Direction {
    EAST, SOUTH, WEST, NORTH;
  }
```

In my algorithm code i cannot call `EAST` in one of my Loops i need to use The `CW` direction, I think this is breaking my algorithm I am getting the following error if i Try to use `EAST`

> PackageName.BoardElement.Direction cannot be converted to
>   android.graphics.Path.Direction

When i use the `CW` Direction the algorithm runs but I get `attempt to read from null array` error

Loop:

```
if(c0 == c1){
            int[] tmp = nextIsland(r0, c0, Path.Direction.CW);
            if(tmp[0] != r1 || tmp[1] != c1)
                return false;
            if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0] == 0 || BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1] == 0)
                return false;
            for (int i = r0; i <= r1 ; i++) {
                if(IS_ISLAND[i][c0])
                    continue;
                if(BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][c0] == EAST) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

The Whole Algorithm

```
public class Land {

private int[][] BRIDGES_TO_BUILD;

private boolean[][] IS_ISLAND;
private Direction[][] BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT;

public Land(int[][] bridgesToDo){
    BRIDGES_TO_BUILD = copy(bridgesToDo);

    int R = bridgesToDo.length;
    int C = bridgesToDo[0].length;
    BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT = new Direction[R][C];
    IS_ISLAND = new boolean[R][C];
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j] = null;
            IS_ISLAND[i][j] = bridgesToDo[i][j] > 0;
        }
    }
}

public Land(Land other){
    BRIDGES_TO_BUILD = copy(other.BRIDGES_TO_BUILD);
    int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
    int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;
    BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT = new Direction[R][C];
    IS_ISLAND = new boolean[R][C];
    for(int i=0;i<R;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j] = other.BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][j];
            IS_ISLAND[i][j] = other.IS_ISLAND[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public int[] next(int r, int c, Path.Direction dir){
    int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
    int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;

    // out of bounds
    if(r < 0 || r >=R || c < 0 || c >= C)
        return null;


    // motion vectors
    int[][] motionVector = {{-1, 0},{0,1},{1,0},{0,-1}};
    int i = Arrays.asList(values()).indexOf(dir);

    // calculate next
    int[] out = new int[]{r + motionVector[i][0], c + motionVector[i][1]};

    r = out[0];
    c = out[1];

    // out of bounds
    if(r < 0 || r >=R || c < 0 || c >= C)
        return null;

    // return
    return out;
}

public int[] nextIsland(int r, int c, Path.Direction dir){
    int[] tmp = next(r,c,dir);
    if(tmp == null)
        return null;
    while(!IS_ISLAND[tmp[0]][tmp[1]]){
        tmp = next(tmp[0], tmp[1], dir);
        if(tmp == null)
            return null;
    }
    return tmp;
}

public boolean canBuildBridge(int r0, int c0, int r1, int c1){
    if(r0 == r1 && c0 > c1){
        return canBuildBridge(r0, c1, r1, c0);
    }
    if(c0 == c1 && r0 > r1){
        return canBuildBridge(r1, c0, r0, c1);
    }

        if (r0 == r1) {
            int[] tmp = nextIsland(r0, c0, Path.Direction.CW//This is where i cannot use "EAST");
            if (tmp[0] != r1 || tmp[1] != c1)
                return false;
            if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0] == 0)
                return false;
            if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1] == 0)
                return false;
            for (int i = c0; i <= c1; i++) {
                if (IS_ISLAND[r0][i])
                    continue;
                if (BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[r0][i] == Direction.NORTH)
                    return false;
            }
        }
    if(c0 == c1){
        int[] tmp = nextIsland(r0, c0, Path.Direction.CW);
        if(tmp[0] != r1 || tmp[1] != c1)
            return false;
        if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0] == 0 || BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1] == 0)
            return false;
        for (int i = r0; i <= r1 ; i++) {
            if(IS_ISLAND[i][c0])
                continue;
            if(BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][c0] == EAST) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // default
    return true;
}

public int[] lowestTodo(){
    int R = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD.length;
    int C = BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[0].length;

    int[] out = {0, 0};
    for (int i=0;i<R;i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            if(BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[i][j] == 0)
                continue;
            if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]] == 0)
                out = new int[]{i, j};
            if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[i][j] < BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]])
                out = new int[]{i, j};
        }
    }
    if (BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[out[0]][out[1]] == 0) {
            return null;
    }
    return out;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
private int[][] copy(int[][] other){
    int[][] out = new int[other.length][other.length == 0 ? 0 : other[0].length];
    for(int r=0;r<other.length;r++)
        out[r] = Arrays.copyOf(other[r], other[r].length);
    return out;
}

public void connect(int r0, int c0, int r1, int c1){
    if(r0 == r1 && c0 > c1){
        connect(r0, c1, r1, c0);
        return;
    }
    if(c0 == c1 && r0 > r1){
        connect(r1, c0, r0, c1);
        return;
    }
    if(!canBuildBridge(r0, c0, r1, c1))
        return;

    BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r0][c0]--;
    BRIDGES_TO_BUILD[r1][c1]--;

    if(r0 == r1){
        for (int i = c0; i <= c1 ; i++) {
            if(IS_ISLAND[r0][i])
                continue;
            BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[r0][i] = Direction.EAST;
        }
    }
    if(c0 == c1){
        for (int i = r0; i <= r1 ; i++) {
            if(IS_ISLAND[i][c0])
                continue;
            BRIDGES_ALREADY_BUILT[i][c0] = Direction.NORTH;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using both `Path.Direction` and your own `Direction` enum simultaneously?

Comment: I am getting errors where my own Direction is not picking up my calls hence i had to use `Path.Direction` That is my question to be honest, How can i just use my own `Enum` ?

Comment: In your next(int, int Path.Direction) method you call a values(). What does this method? And it could be okay that you need two enums that happen to have the same name. But mixing them, or trying to replace them with each other like this can't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `android.graphics.Path.Direction` when you should be importing `PackageName.BoardElement.Direction`. Despite being named the same, those are two separate classes and one can't be substituted for the other.

Remove the first import and replace `Path.Direction`with just `Direction` and I believe you'll get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, I got mixed up with `Path.Direction.dir` It should be `Direction dir` thats why the `EAST` direction wouldn't work it was getting mixed up.